# Ember - nested recursive modules

Tags: javascript, recursion, ember.js

I am working on an click and drop feature --- where on the page the module is used in a recursive way so it has a parent and children.

I have hit an issue where if the user started to select the children - and then selects the parent - I want to deselect the children. Although I am unsure how to store or monitor a change in the parent/child items selected to make global deselection.

So the user has selected the child of bacon3.. if they select the parent - it would need to deselect the children -- but I feel I am currently locked in the scope of the module

[image]

Comment: Could you share some more information about your data and action flow? Data down, action up pattern is considered best practice.

Comment: The module is nested within itself --- --  <module>  content <module></module></module>  -- the js for the module is working fine for actions within in itself - but communication between parent, child modules - not sure what to do

Comment: If it's about data and action flow between nested components I would recommend reading some articles about DDAU (data down, actions up) pattern.

Comment: but they are inside each other -- I need to isolate that if the children elements are clicked to abandon the parent state -- vice versa -- I got action click events in the module itself - but its like I've lost scope of how to communicate between a parent and child component.

Comment: Please provide an ember twiddle with your current implementation.

Comment: Do you have a base version for me to start showing - its a complicated piece. You able to create the ember twiddle demo for me?

Comment: Anything that shows a recursive module -- then on click - of a checkbox in the module - can tell if the parent/child is selected -- its about trying to deselect the children if the parent gets selected -- or deselect the parent if the children starts to get selected

Comment: In some cases where different routes and components need shared state, the answer may be to either put it in a query parameter or make a service.

Comment: Its a very complicated site - the issue is more pure javascript based

Comment: Here is an ember twiddle -- this is the problem I have -- I can register clicks on the checkboxes -- but what I want to do - is in this nested state - detect if the child was clicked first -- then if the parent is clicked - uncheck the child -- vice versa -- eg.. if the parent is clicked first then the child - uncheck the parent. https://ember-twiddle.com/dd49cdf95a4a9dee05dea1650af5ddab?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2C   -- I feel like I am just stuck inside this component and unable to communicate with its other instance

Comment: @jelhan https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/2e0251e78f25976494a37af7f6d16d8b?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C

Comment: latest ember twiddle -- tried to collect the group ids to determine if the user has clicked off to another group. https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/2ba652b74684ce31238c7409c4720af5?openFiles=components.checkbox-component.js%2C

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time to provide a full implementation cause that's a more complex one. But I don't think it's to complex if you follow the rules of data down, actions up-principle: Represent which items are selected in controller / service. Implement methods to change selected state in controller / service. Pass data (items and if they are selected) as well as actions down to your components. Trigger the actions depending on users interaction. Don't hold information which item is selected in the component. Don't change that data in the component. Data down, actions up!

Comment: I would need to clear the states of selected lists for other parts of the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this example will help you https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/468a737efbbf447966dd83ac734f62ad?openFiles=utils.tree-helpers.js%2C

So, this was an interesting problem. It turned out to be more of a recursion problem than anything having to do with ember, javascript, or checkbox behavior.

Here is what I have (using the updated syntax and such (if you have the option to upgrade to 3.4, you most definitely should -- it's a dream))

```
// wrapping-component.js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action, computed } from '@ember-decorators/object';

import { check } from 'twiddle/utils/tree-helpers';

export default class extends Component {  
  options = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'burger',
    checked: false,
    children: [{
        id: 3,
      label: 'tomato',
      checked: false
    }, {
        id: 4,
      label: 'lettus',
      checked: false    
    }, {
      id: 5,
      label: 'pickle',
      checked: false
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'kebab',
    checked: false,
    children: [{
        id: 6,
      label: 'ketchup',
      checked: false
    }, {
      id: 7,
      label: 'chilli',
      checked: false
    }]
  }];

  @action
  toggleChecked(id) {
    const newTree = check(this.options, id);

    this.set('options', newTree);
  }
}
```

template:

```
{{yield this.options (action this.toggleChecked)}}
```

and the usage:

```
// application.hbs
<WrappingComponent as |options toggle|>
  {{#each options as |item|}}

    <CheckboxGroup @item={{item}} @onClick={{toggle}} />

  {{/each}}
</WrappingComponent>
```

CheckboxGroup is a template-only component:

```
// checkbox-group.hbs
<div class="checkboxhandler">
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked={{@item.checked}}
    onclick={{action @onClick @item.id}}
  >
  <label>{{@item.label}}</label>

  {{#if @item.children}}
    {{#each @item.children as |child|}}

       <CheckboxGroup @item={{child}} @onClick={{@onClick}} />

    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

and the recursive helpers (this is a mess, but I've just been prototyping):

```
// utils/tree-helpers.js
const toggle = value => !value;
const disable = () => false;

// the roots / siblings are contained by arrays
export function check(tree, id, transform = toggle) {
  if (tree === undefined) return undefined;

  if (Array.isArray(tree)) {
    return selectOnlySubtree(tree, id, transform);  
  } 

  if (tree.id === id || id === 'all') {
    return checkNode(tree, id, transform);
  }

  if (tree.children) {
    return checkChildren(tree, id, transform);
  }

  return tree;
}

function selectOnlySubtree(tree, id, transform) {
  return tree.map(subTree => {
    const newTree = check(subTree, id, transform);

    if (!newTree.children || (transform !== disable && didChange(newTree, subTree))) {
      return newTree;
    } 

    return disableTree(subTree);
  });
}

function isTargetAtThisLevel(tree, id) {
  return tree.map(t => t.id).includes(id);
}

function checkNode(tree, id, transform) {
  return { 
    ...tree, 
    checked: transform(tree.checked),
    children: disableTree(tree.children)
  };
}

function disableTree(tree) {
  return check(tree, 'all', disable);
}

function checkChildren(tree, id, transform) {
    return { 
        ...tree, 
        checked: id === 'all' ? transform(tree.checked) : tree.checked,
    children: check(tree.children, id, transform) 
  };
}

export function didChange(treeA, treeB) {
  const rootsChanged = treeA.checked !== treeB.checked;

  if (rootsChanged) return true;

  if (treeA.children && treeB.children) {
    const compares = treeA.children.map((childA, index) => {
      return didChange(childA, treeB.children[index]);
    });

    const nothingChanged = compares.every(v => v === false);

    return !nothingChanged;
  }

  return false;
}
```

hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/2ba652b74684ce31238c7409c4720af5?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C -- this is the latest fiddle

Comment: No this still doesn't work as expected. If burger and kebab are checked, then the user clicks on ketchup - (burger and kebab become unchecked). If burger is checked and then the user selects tomato, burger becomes unchecked. If tomato is checked then the user selects ketchup, tomato becomes unchecked

Comment: I didn't have it _complete_, it's just most of the way there. I'm deliberately not solving this all the way each time I report back in case I inspire you to figure out the rest. 
I'll keep going though

Comment: I'm reviewing it still - trying to implement some of the other key aspects of it. Would need to remap data to push into this module - as the data will be different for a bulk of other parts on this site

Comment: I've added the selectedId array -- although it doesn't remove the object as my code base does -- https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/d507d9ff2d7802fd0a4ee946a474dee9?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C  -- essentially this array needs to be emptied reset - along with the reset checkboxes

Comment: Also the project here is using Ember "2.13.4"

Comment: cool, I'm still working on getting the nested tree disabling.
Ember doesn't matter at this point. I'm just doing pure js now.

Comment: sure sure - I am trying to understand how the tree enabling/disabling functionality is intended to work in your version

Comment: I now have the checkboxes behaving _closer_ to what you want: https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/468a737efbbf447966dd83ac734f62ad?openFiles=utils.tree-helpers.js%2C

I think I still need to be able to select tomato and lettus at the same time though

Comment: I think I did it!

Comment: but its not working if you select burger and kebab -- these need to stick on - as they are a "parent group" ---

Comment: oh, well, I misunderstood entirely.
I had it so only one tree could be selected at a time.
but you're saying... parents can be selected without restriction, but if a child is selected in one tree, it must deselect all children in the other tree?

Comment: I think your application nearly works - except for if burger+kebab are selected they need to stick - that's a valid condition. --- Essentially you always ONLY have one active group --- if be the parent group --- or the children of a parent -- so going from a parent to a child - deselects the parent.... going from child to parent - deselects the child.... going from children of parent 1 to children of parent 2 - deselects children of parent 1

Comment: those conditions confuse me, as what your describe conflicts in my head.

Is there anyway you can flesh out some unit tests that describe this behavior?

Comment: --- burger and kebab are parents -- they are the same group so selecting these is a valid condition.

Comment: gotchya. 
I have the children deselecting the parent.
All that's left is allow the burger and kebab to be selected at the same time

Comment: @TheOldCounty how about now? https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/468a737efbbf447966dd83ac734f62ad?openFiles=tests.unit.utils.tree-helper-test.js%2C

Comment: functionality broke. Let me list the conditions

Comment: if burger+kebab are checked. Then user selects tomato, burger+kebab are dechecked. (currently only burger get deselected)

Comment: if burger is checked. Then the user selects tomato, burger is deselected (this works currently)

Comment: Is this enough for you to continue on your own? :-\
Hopefully the logic is clear in the utils file is clear

Comment: if tomato is checked. Then the user selects burger, tomato is deselected (this works currently)

Comment: if lettus is checked and then the user selects ketchup, lettus becomes unchecked (this doesn't work)

Comment: the helper is a bit hard coded man - it only assumes there will be two trees -- there could be more than 2 parents -- could be a 3rd parent, 4th

Comment: it's recursive, so it could be unlimited. I'll update showing that.

Comment: I just added a third top-level group _only_ be adding to the `options' array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181147/discussion-between-nullvoxpopuli-and-the-old-county).

Comment: * currently - I can select chilli - then burger - and no decheck of chilli occurs - so that's a bug
* currently - I can select coffee maker - then pickle - and no decheck of coffee maker occurs - so that's a bug
* currently - I can select filter - then chilli - and no decheck of filter occurs - so that's a bug

Comment: Why do you want it to behave that way? Seems unintuitive to me

Comment: its full functionality is like a click and drop -- so you can select multiple items from a group and move them around.

Comment: ok, I'll spend some time over lunch trying to get it behaving in that way

Comment: well, riddle me this:
why does it make sense to be able to select multiple top-level things, but not multiple second level things?

Comment: Its a click and drag feature ---- I click on parents then the option comes up to move the parents around --- if I click on children the option is to move the children around. --- if I start to click parents, then change my mind and click on a child I need to discard the intent to move the parents around... if I click on a child in parent 0 -- then click on a child in parent 1 - -I need to discard the intent to move the children in parent 0.

Comment: So, is this whole thing with checkboxes even worth while?

Comment: It is how it needs to be. Your stuff nearly works except for those bugs - its hard to reverse engineer some of your code -- also when I tried to folk it before lunch - came up with some error in the actions

Comment: Well, I'm not going to implement everything for you, so... I'm drawing the line here.
You have what you need to get the behavior -- the logic you want to implement should probably live in checkChildren and / or be pull in some things from selectOnlySubtree. 
I don't know if recursion is new to you or not, but It's worthwhile for you to learn.
Here are some resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849422/practical-tips-debugging-deep-recursion

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-debug-a-recursive-algorithm

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306478/debugging-mutually-recursive-functions

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tracing-stack-during-recursive-function-call-sreekantappa-gayathri/


I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: @TheOldCounty I recommend pair programming with a colleague if you have that option. :)

Comment: Its the same brief as it was - but I am not sure why your code isn't functioning as well as it used to -- before you tried to get the parents to select more than one parent - it was close to complete -- but when you allowed the parents to be be multi-selectable the functionality came into bugs.

Comment: Alright I'll give the bounty - but its a broken application still. I'll need to troubleshoot it further

Comment: @TheOldCounty thanks so much.
As for why the behavior has changed, it's because of me not understanding what you wanted initially, and kind of what happens when recursively applying the same function over layers of a tree.

I'm happy to help out with other ember-related issues in new questions, or non-ember questions if they can be boiled down enough. :)

Also! unit tests do wonders for expressing intent. Highly recommend for future questions involving twiddles. :+1:

Comment: I'm building the actual groovy tests this side of the fence. But I am unsure how to resolve the issue - as well as restructure it in the way you did with a clean model. The data isn't clean - and its a very very large enterprise level application - this problem is only coming about because of a UX fine-tune

Comment: there is an error that comes up trying to folk the twiddle? It produces some error in actions. Also need to store the array and empty the array when its no longer in focus

Comment: you could copy all the files to a new twiddle and see if that works? otherwise a bug may have been introduced, and we may need to report it to the twiddle devs

Comment: ok I've recreated it - the enhancement continues  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610960/ember-one-focus-active-list-recursive-problem

Comment: thanks! I'll share that link with other people who like to help out on stack overflow -- hopefully it gets some traction.

Comment: be good to clean up the code a bit and write some comments. I'm removing the old data in application.js

Comment: https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs -- I've updated it -- and started to create the array of the selected items -- but it still has that bug of not removing deselected items.

Comment: possible solution - please check https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs