# How do I recursively de-select cousin nodes when selecting sibling nodes (recursively rendered checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, recursion, ember.js

I am building a multi-select checkdown group item list. The goal is to have only ONE active group at a time. So the user can select parents - but if they select a child item, that child group becomes the focus and the selected parents become unchecked.

```
<div class="checkboxhandler">
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked={{@item.checked}}
    onclick={{action @onClick @item.id}}
  >
  <label>{{@item.label}} -- checked: {{@item.checked}}</label>

  {{#if @item.children}}
    {{#each @item.children as |child|}}

       <CheckboxGroup @item={{child}} @onClick={{@onClick}} />

    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

I've got as far with the checkboxes with recursive helper checks.

This is the helper tree - where the logic to deselect takes place. This application also needs to hold the array for selectedItems - but needs to clear those array's as well as the checkboxes.

```
const toggle = value => !value;
const disable = () => false;

// the roots / siblings are contained by arrays
export function check(tree, id, transform = toggle) {
  if (tree === undefined) return undefined;

  if (Array.isArray(tree)) {
    return tree.map(t => check(t, id, transform));
  } 

  if (tree.id === id || id === 'all') {
    return checkNode(tree, id, transform);
  }

  if (tree.children) {
    return checkChildren(tree, id, transform);
  }

  return tree;
}

function selectOnlySubtree(tree, id, transform) {
  return tree.map(subTree => {
    const newTree = check(subTree, id, transform);

    if (!newTree.children || (transform !== disable && didChange(newTree, subTree))) {
      return newTree;
    } 

    return disableTree(subTree);
  });
}

function isTargetAtThisLevel(tree, id) {
  return tree.map(t => t.id).includes(id);
}

function checkNode(tree, id, transform) {
  return { 
    ...tree, 
    checked: transform(tree.checked),
    children: disableTree(tree.children)
  };
}

function disableTree(tree) {
  return check(tree, 'all', disable);
}

function checkChildren(tree, id, transform) {
  const newChildren = check(tree.children, id, transform);
  const changed = didChange(tree.children, newChildren);
  const checked = changed ? false : (
    id === 'all' ? transform(tree.checked) : tree.checked
  );

    return { 
        ...tree, 
        checked: checked,
    children: check(tree.children, id, transform) 
  };
}

export function didChange(treeA, treeB) {
  const rootsChanged = treeA.checked !== treeB.checked;

  if (rootsChanged) return true;

  if (Array.isArray(treeA) && Array.isArray(treeB)) {
    return didChangeList(treeA, treeB);
  }

  if (treeA.children && treeB.children) {
        return didChangeList(treeA.children, treeB.children);
  }

  return false;
}

function didChangeList(a, b) {
  const compares = a.map((childA, index) => {
    return didChange(childA, b[index]);
  });

  const nothingChanged = compares.every(v => v === false);

  return !nothingChanged;
}
```

//latest ember fiddle
https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs

so these are valid conditions
-- just parents selected
[image]

-- just children selected
[image]

but the current bugs are occuring

1. currently - I can select chilli - then burger - and no decheck of
   chilli occurs - so that's a bug
2. currently - I can select coffee maker - then pickle - and no decheck of coffee maker occurs - so that's a bug
3. currently - I can select filter - then chilli - and no decheck of filter occurs - so that's a bug

//illustration of error 1 - so only burger should remain selected in this instance
[image]

//illustration of error 2 - so only pickle should remain selected in this instance
[image]

//illustration of problem 3 - so only chilli should remain selected in this instance
[image]

Comment: possible solution - please check https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs

Answer (score 1):

You could, after every `false -> true` transition, uncheck the whole tree *except* the layer that includes the item that's currently being updated.

For example:

- Loop over a layer
- Check if the item that's being set to true is in the layer using `.find`

  - If it is:

    - Set it's `checked` property to `true`
    - Skip the other items
  - If it is not:

    - Set all items to `checked: false`
- Recurse for every item with a `children` array

```js
const turnOn = (options, id) => {
  const target = options.find(o => o.id === id);

  if (target) {
    target.checked = true;        
  } else {
    options.forEach(o => { o.checked = false; })
  }

  // Recurse
  options.forEach(({ children = [] }) => turnOn(children, id));
}

var opts = options();

turnOn(opts, 3);
turnOn(opts, 4);
console.log("Checked after 3 & 4:", getChecked(opts));

turnOn(opts, 2);
console.log("Checked after 2:", getChecked(opts));

turnOn(opts, 6);
console.log("Checked after 6:", getChecked(opts));





function options() {
  return [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'burger',
    checked: false,
    children: [{
      id: 3,
      label: 'tomato',
      checked: false
    }, {
      id: 4,
      label: 'lettus',
      checked: false
    }, {
      id: 5,
      label: 'pickle',
      checked: false
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'kebab',
    checked: false,
    children: [{
      id: 6,
      label: 'ketchup',
      checked: false
    }, {
      id: 7,
      label: 'chilli',
      checked: false
    }]
  }];
};

function getChecked(opts) {
  return opts.reduce((acc, o) => acc.concat(
    o.checked ? o.label : [],
    getChecked(o.children || [])
  ), []);
}
```

<sub>Note: I went with a recursive function that simply mutates the tree rather than returning a new one because it's easier to read</sub>

Comment: you able to edit the twiddle -- https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs   -- there is also a selectedItem array that needs to be cleaned

Comment: The `getChecked` shows how you can update the `selectedItem` array without relying on events and mutations. It's a computation based on the tree that returns a flat array of items that have `item.checked === true`.

Comment: The logic you're requiring has the ability to change many values at once. Currently, you're only adding/removing the clicked item. When checking an item, there's no guarantee that's the only change. Therefore it seems like a better option to simply clear the whole selected state and recalculate it using a pure `tree -> [ item ]` function.

Comment: Sure - but the tree is still corrupt in invoking true states when they should be reverted to false

Comment: Your current solution can only disable child items, not parent items. `checkNode` only calls `disableTree` on its children; the layers above it have already been processed and were ignored.

Comment: parent items can get disabled by the children -- but its handling cousin situations -- like parent 0 selected -- then parent 1 child selected --

Comment: you able to include it in the ember twiddle - to test it?

Comment: possible solution - please check https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f28edbf72193427c2a527e51d57e759f?openFiles=components.wrapping-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-group.hbs

Answer (score 0):

I think you could actually benefit a *lot* if you would stop storing the information if a item is selected on that item itself. This will also save you from the problem to modify the items. Just store an array of selected ids separately to the data. Next you only need one helper, [`contains`/`includes`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#contains).

So you can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{contains item.id selectedIds}} />
```

Next your ruleset was pretty simple. A valid selection contains only items of the same *group*. A group may be

1. all parents, or
2. all children of the same parent.

Now it's far easier to not deselect some items, but assuming that one item *must* be selected (the one you clicked on) to verify which already selected items are still valid selections. And thats pretty easy: all that are in the same group.

So first we find the group for the `id` of the item the user clicked on. If the list of parents contains the `id` then we use the list of parents, otherwise we find the parent which `children` contains the id:

```
const group = data.find(x => x.id === id)
  ? data
  : data.find(p => p.children.find(c => c.id === id)).children;
```

Now we have the group. To get all `id`s of the group we do `const validIds = group.map(x => x.id)`.

Next the new `selectedIds` should be:

- the `id` of the item the user clicked on,
- and all old `selectedIds` that are also in `validIds`.

We can do this like this:

```
const newSelectedIds = [
  id,
  ...oldSelectedIds.filter(s => validIds.includes(s)),
];
```

[here is a twiddle implementing this approach](https://ember-twiddle.com/f7965319bd2e061c5f6bab2a94807dda?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

---

If you use `ember-data` for your data you can actually simplify this even more. If you have a relationship between parents and children, you can follow the relationship in *both ways*. So you can find all siblings by something like `item.parent.children`. Then you can pass the model instead of just the `id` to the function and find the valid group with something like this:

```
const group = item instanceof ParentModel
  ? this.data
  : item.parent.children;
```

which is a bit more readable.